# 3D intersection (Radiosity) - OpenGl

Tags: opengl, visibility, patch

I am trying to compute the visibility between two planes or patches.

I have a wireframe of quads. Each quad has a normal vector with X, Y and Z coordinates. Each quad has 4 vertices. Each vertex has X, Y and Z coordinates.

Given two quads, how can I know if there is an occluder or another object in between these two patches (quads).

[image]

Therefore, I need to create a method that returns 1 if patches has no occluders or return 0 if patches has occluder.

The method I picture would be something like this:

```
GLint visibility(Patch i, Patch j) {

    GLboolean isVisible;
    vector<Patch> allPatches; // can be used to get all patches in the scene

    // Check if there is any occluder between patch i and patch j
    Some computations here

    if(isVisible) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I've heard of z-buffer algorithms and the hemicube implementation that would get this done.  I already have the form-factors computed. I just need to finish this step to get shadows.

Make sure you give some form of answer with graphs or methods because I am not that genius

Comment: how are you handling partial visibility? most discussion I've seen about this just sends random rays and tests against those

Comment: You could test for intersection between the volume containing both of the quads... in other words, create a box with ends Patch i and Patch j and then test to see if any objects in the scene have a point inside this box or if the object intersects the box in any way.

Comment: that didn't help much guys :x

Comment: Why not? That is the simplest way to effectively perform an infinite number of ray tests from all possible points in Patch i to Patch j. Turn the space in-between the two patches into a volume and then do intersection tests on that volume to find occlusion. But you must also consider objects that are entirely inside the volume (they will occlude but not intersect). Since the two patches are quads in this example the volume is a box, and intersection vs. boxes are trivial.

Comment: Sorry but my maths is not that good. I see what you mean, but in no ways I will be able to implement that. Can you write at least some pseudo code so I get it? Have no idea how to create this volume you talking about! I am doing this since December, if it was easy for me I would never come here :x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Basically I needed to use ray tracing techniques. Throw ray from one patch to another and check if ray intercepts the planes with barycentric equation computation. Once you find the control points you need to check if the control point lies on you quad.